# Setting up the EB CLI - error nonetype get_frozen_credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, osx-elcapitan, amazon-ec2

```
Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
7) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
8) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
9) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
10) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
11) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
(default is 3):5
```

When I choose a number or just leave it blank.. the following error appears:

> ERROR: AttributeError :: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 
>   'get_frozen_credentials'

after running eb init --debug:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 11,
>   in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebcore.py", line 149, in
>   main
>       app.run()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line
>   694, in run
>           self.controller._dispatch()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line
>   455, in _dispatch
>           return func()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line
>   461, in _dispatch
>           return func()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py",
>   line 57, in default
>           self.do_command()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py",
>   line 67, in do_command
>           self.set_up_credentials()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py",
>   line 152, in set_up_credentials
>           if not initializeops.credentials_are_valid():
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/initializeops.py",
>   line 24, in credentials_are_valid
>           elasticbeanstalk.get_available_solution_stacks()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/elasticbeanstalk.py",
>   line 239, in get_available_solution_stacks
>           result = _make_api_call('list_available_solution_stacks')
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/elasticbeanstalk.py",
>   line 37, in _make_api_call
>           **operation_options)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 207, in make_api_call
>           response_data = operation(**operation_options)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
>           return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 396, in _make_api_call
>           operation_model, request_dict)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 111, in make_request
>           return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 136, in _send_request
>           request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 120, in create_request
>           operation_name=operation_model.name)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit
>           return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit
>           response = handler(**kwargs)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
>           return self.sign(operation_name, request)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 123, in sign
>           signature_version)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 153, in get_auth_instance
>           kwargs['credentials'] = self._credentials.get_frozen_credentials()
>       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_frozen_credentials'

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Comment: FWIW, I get the same error message (and same trace starting from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py`) following [this quickstart tutorial](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html) on Ubuntu Trusty.

Comment: Was it working before, or is it the first time you try ?

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou first time yes, normally I ssh'd into the instance without eb cli

Comment: In my case I solved it by providing the credentials in the right place (I misread `~/.aws/credentials` for `.aws/credentials`).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You got this error because you didn't initialize your `AWS Access Key ID` and `AWS Secret Access Key`
you should install first awscli by runing `pip install awscli`.

After you need to configure aws: 
`aws configure`

After this you can run `eb init`

Comment: @sadoknet tnx for updating!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this error as well. Not sure of the root cause. But am still on Yosemite. When I tried AWS's install script 
`curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-cli-resources/install-ebcli.py | python`
It downloaded EB CLI 3.7.3 (Python 2.7.1). A co-worker tried on his machine using homebrew and (since he hadn't run brew update in awhile) managed to get version 3.5.4 which worked perfectly.

Looks like Amazon may have broken something in the updates for Yosemite users so rather than wait I just downloaded the working version and had no issues running `eb init`

Here's the steps I took:

1. Amazon created a symlink to version 3.7 in `usr/local/bin` called `eb`. Remove this link `rm /usr/local/bin/eb`
2. `cd /usr/local/Library`
3. Use homebrew's `brew log awsebcli` to find the sha for the updated commit of version 3.5.4 (21e20f5).
4. Run `git checkout 21e20f5 /usr/local/Library/Formula/aws-elasticbeanstalk.rb`
5. Run `brew install awsebcli` and `eb init` should now run properly.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I facing the same problem, running eb for the first time on Arch Linux.

What worked for me was instead of simply using 
`eb init`

try a parameterized init, for example for interactive init

```
eb init -i
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I installed aws-cli ( brew install awsebcli )

Next, run "aws configure" and provide the correct details.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Was also had same issue but solved it some how. As I was doing it for first time I prefer to follow step by step documentation but lead to above issue but solved by following simple steps

```
$ mkdir HelloWorld
$ cd HelloWorld
$ eb init -p PHP
$ echo "Hello World" > index.html
$ eb create dev-env
$ eb open
```

In my case while following document steps I never asked for id/secret but with above commands it was possible.

Hope it work for you!

Answer (score 0):

With credentials stored in `~/.aws/credentials` and even after calling `aws configure`, I still had to use `--profile profile_name` with the command that was failing with the "no attribute 'get_frozen_credentials'" error. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but none of the above helped me.  My problem was solved after creating an IAM user http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html and generating new keys for it instead of using root and root keys and doing things the legacy way.